# How do you distribute a spring batch job effectively across jvms?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

In the job I read from a file and store something in a database.
I would like to have many running jars of the batch job in different processes and partition the data from the file among the running instances.

I would also like to be able to keep adding files to be processed and also distribute the reads from those.
I read spring xd might be a good fit, but can't find good tutorials on it.
YES I am also a noob of spring batch and xd.

Comment: so this is the console tutorial after you set up spring xd https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/Creating-a-Job-Module.asciidoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is how to remotely partition batch jobs. See the [batch documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#remote-partitioning) for Spring Batch Integration and its support for remote partitioning, based on basic [batch partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning).

Spring XD provides out-of-the-box support for single-step partitioned work-loads.

You just have to import `singlestep-partition-support.xml` and provide partitioner and tasklet beans. See the [XD Documentation for an example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#batch).

Comment: so let's say I have a spring boot and mvc jar that launches jobs from a controller, and it also has remote partitioning; I could then simply say ' module upload ......... --type processor' ? and afterwards how would I deploy more instances?  or does the remote partitioning need to be completely separated from any spring mvc or boot to be uploaded as '--type job'?

Comment: No; it needs to be an XD job module and uploaded as such and you determine the instance count when deploying the job. You have to use XD's job launching mechanism. If you have a partitioned job in your own war, you can simply deploy multiple instances; but you have to use your own infrastructure (JMS, RabbitMQ etc) to distribute the partitions to the worker instances using the sample code in the `spring-batch-integration` project.

Comment: and if I'd want to send json arrays as a http request to start the job, I would have to add a source module and then link the source to the job module?

Comment: Yes; there's an example under [Launch job as a part of event flow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_launching_a_job) (scroll down a bit).