# how to distribute load of batch job events between nodes(different servers)

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have large events in a table, of a job. how can i distribute these events between servers of active-active setup currently we have implemented spring batch with local partitioning.

i just built the spring batch with remote partitioning. used JMS for messaging. now i want run two tomcats with same code cloned. how to ensure that job events are distribute to both servers. At First job request goes to any one server after based and partitioning, table events will be divide to few groups as per our requirement and distribute then to each server and execute. how can i do this pls help me. i added same in comment.
excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you distribute a spring batch job effectively across jvms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023555/how-do-you-distribute-a-spring-batch-job-effectively-across-jvms)

Comment: Thanks Beskrovnov.

Comment: Hi Beskrovnov i just built the spring batch with remote partitioning.
used JMS for messaging. now i want run two tomcats with same code cloned. how to ensure that job events are distribute to both servers.
first job request goes to any one server after based and partitioning table events will be divide to few groups as per our requirement and distribute then to each server and execute.